# Laravel eloquent returns an unsigned integer column's records limited to 2147483647

Tags: php, mysql, windows, laravel, eloquent

So I have this column in MySQL with unsigned integer data type of which some of the records values are bigger than 2147483647, the max positive number of a signed integer.

I ran a query with Laravel's eloquent ORM but the records with a value bigger than 2147483647 were returned as 2147483647. I read somewhere that eloquent has some issues with windows, which is the OS I'm using right now with XAMPP environment. And so I tried using the query builder instead of eloquent ORM and turned out the values were returned correctly. I haven't tried running the code on the other OS though, I'll try and do it then come back with an update, but finding out in which OS it's working is not the main reason I'm coming here.

I'm still a student right now and new to Laravel, so I was wondering if someone can shed a light on the matter as to what could have caused that and what to consider if I were to use Laravel eloquent in the future.

Comment: I believe your question was answered here:
[Laravel bigInteger being rounded to int in relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688889/laravel-biginteger-being-rounded-to-int-in-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

It's MySQL constraint, so you can just use [`BIGINT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) with max value of `18446744073709551615`:

```
$table->bigInteger('votes'); // For columns.
$table->bigIncrements('id'); // For keys.
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns

Comment: I already did that but turned out to be the same. Still returned 2147483647 with eloquent and correct values with query builder. I checked the table in phpmyadmin before and after i changed the column to bigint and the values there are correct both of the times